# Why is Edit available on some sites but not others?

Tags: editing-menu

[image: No edit]

[image: Edit]

I created all of the sites in our team site... But "Edit: is not available on all of them? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to choose edit page from the "gear menu"? To make sure you have correct permissions.

Comment: Yes, From the gear menu I can choose "edit". Then the Page Tab opens, but the ribbon tools are very limited... I don't see things like 'styles' and the change 'column layout' tools?

Comment: I've gone to 'Check permissions' on a given site, that does not show 'edit' and My credentials says "Allow" under ALL.

Comment: Wait... Is edit not available on project sites? but edit is available on team sites? Is that the difference? If so how do you change a project site into a team site?

Comment: I believe that it's possible to change the site template after creation but it's not best practise.

Comment: In my case, edit button disabled when page is published.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking

> Show Ribbon

In the gear menu

[image: No Edit]

[image: Edit!]